# 403 код ответа на запрос к ресурсу geocode-maps.yandex.ru

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Получаю код ответа 403 на запрос к ресурсу geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=a69a8cd1-c6b6-44a4-9ce0-eb47c704aaa9&format=json&results=1&geocode=143132, 143132, Московская обл, г Руза, рп Тучково, ул Партизан, д 11

Comment: ну вот собсна у вас в ответе под `message` стоит `Invalid key`

Comment: Вы открыли правильный api ключ?

Comment: Какое-то время назад этот ключ был рабочим судя по всему. К кому можно обратится за корректным ключом?

Comment: Естественно к Яндексу

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если тариф платный, стоит проверить баланс счёта и общее состояние ключа в [кабинете разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/). Да и для бесплатных тарифов это действие будет верным.

Если ключ оказался заблокирован не вами и баланс здесь не при чём,следует обратиться в [поддержку API Яндекс Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/troubleshooting#feedback). Они подскажут и причину и дальнейшие шаги.

Засвеченный вами ключ лучше всего после решения вопроса его работы заблокировать, предварительно выпустив новый в кабинете разработчика и [привязав его на всякий случай к IP-адресу сервера](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/limit), с которого должны выполняться запросы.

Comment: Спасибо! Дело было в балансе.